# find and replace word using dictionary in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I need to replace a word AAAA in a file using dictionary:

dictionary.txt

```
AXF1
ZCFA
ZCCC
```

Dictionary is about 1500 words.
I need to replace AAAA by AXF1 then I need to find next AAAA and replace by ZCFA...
Any idea how can I do this? Everything that I have found is how to replace like this:

```
AAA1:AXF1
AAA2:ZCFA
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
# Read dictionary into memory
dictionary = [line.strip() for line in open('dictionary.txt')]

# Assuming a bit of a wrap around may be required depending on num. of AAAA's
from itertools import cycle
cyclic_dictionary = cycle(dictionary)

# Read main file
other_file = open('filename').read()

# Let's replace all the AAAA's
import re
re.sub('A{4}', lambda L: next(cyclic_dictionary), other_file, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR == NR {list[c++] = $1; next}
{
    while (sub("AAAA", list[n++])) {
        n %= c
    }
    print
}' list.txt inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >dictionary.txt
> AXF1
> ZCFA
> ZCCC
> !
cat <<\! >file.txt
> a
> b
> AAAA
> c
> AAAA
> d
> AAAA
> !
sed -e '/AAAA/{R dictionary.txt' -e ';d}' file.txt
a
b
AXF1
c
ZCFA 
d 
ZCCC
```